How to pass the session cookie to a subsequent request when writing an integration test using the WebApplicationFactory
I'm trying to implement some integration tests to a website/api project using the WebApplicationFactory<TEntry>.
As found in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0 cookies should be handled by default.

CreateClient() creates an instance of HttpClient that automatically follows redirects and handles cookies.

i've created a custom overload of the WebApplicationFactory where deplendencies for the actual backends are replaces by mock implementations (returning json content from local files) like:
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.ReplaceDependencies<IDefaultsClient, DefaultsClientMock>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
        });

        builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
    }
}

Within my application startup i enabled Session int the program.cs using:
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "custom_session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(builder.Configuration.GetValue<int>("SessionDefaults:IdleTimeoutInMinutes"));
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

My integration tests are based on state so i have to do multiple calls the create the specific state. So after the CreateClient() method i implemented multiple calls using client.GetAsync("dummyUrl); and client.PostAsync("dummyUrl", content);
The first call receices a "set-cookie" in the headers but all subsequest requests don't sent this cookie in the requests. What am i missing?
Kind regards,
Luuk Krijnen
